# Ria Service(Silverlight 4 Tools) in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, wcf-ria-services

Having Visual Studio 2010 SP1, where everything is fine, I can create Silverlight Unit Test Project, RIA Services Class Library, etc 
I installed Visual Studio 2012, then I'm creating a RIA Services Class Library when I noticed  that don't exist 'Domain Service Class', neither Silverlight Unit Test.
What I need to develop RIA Services with Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tools for Silverlight 5 get installed with Visual Studio 2012. May be you need to reinstalled the Tools for Silverlight 4 again.

You can check if your installation of Visual Studio 2012 supports Silverlight 4 by creating a new Silverlight Application project. In the dialog that pops up you can select (ComboBox) the Silverlight Version you want to use in your project.

See also [this post](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/06/do-i-need-to-install-silverlight-tools.html) for further reference.