# Cannot create a domain service class in VS 2012

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm creating a Silverlight project in VS 2012.
I have a simple data source provided by a .cs class and I would like to create a Domain Service Class and add it to the project.
Sadly, there is no such entry when I try to add an element to the project.

I'm sure the entry was there is VS 2010, why did it disappear in VS 2012?
How can I create a Domain Service Class in VS 2012?

Answer (score 1):

You have added an EDMX already? I believe this is because of the change from ObjectContext to dbContext, and there are now a few extra steps to go through if you want to do things the older way ...

http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/vs2012-edmx-defaults-now-align-with-ef-team-guidance-re-dbcontext-usage/#comment-3891
...

After adding your model (EDMX) and installing the nuGet for WCFRIAServices, you will need to follow the steps given to remove the .tt files, rebuild the project, and then you should be able to add your Domain Service as before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not planning to add a EDMX data source, my data model is extremely simple and is contained in a .cs class.

Comment: Ah, in that case start with the basics.  Have a look at this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603952/ria-servicesilverlight-4-tools-in-visual-studio-2012